# Encode String to UTF-8 in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, encoding, character-encoding

Often times when dealing with json and responses you want to encode String to UTF-8 in java.

```
String response = new String(response.data, UTF); // java code
```

For Kotlin, how is this done? I converted my Java class and the result was

```
String response = String(response.data, UTF) // kotlin code
```

But this results in an error, because I believe the Kotlin String() method is different than what I am doing in Java. Is it as simple as using the toString()?

```
String response = response.data.toString() // kotlin code
```

How does the system know to use UTF-8, or is that just the default? This is just hypothetical, but what if I wanted to do something with String object and therefore used UTF-16? How can I change the encoding?

Comment: If you're starting with some byte data, and ending with a String, aren't you **decoding from** UTF8?  (The background here is that characters are (in Java/Kotlin, anyway) 16-bit, and UTF-8 is a way of encoding those Unicode characters into 8-bit bytes.  So if `response.data` is already in UTF-8, then this is decoding; or if not, then I don't know what this question is about!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin has [an overload](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-string.html) of `ByteArray.toString` accepting a `Charset`.  All you need to do is use it: `array.toString(charset)`.

I cannot find a section in the documentation specifying that `ByteArray.toString()` does the right thing, as it *doesn't* in Java and that behavior probably is preserved in Kotlin.  I would guess it does the wrong thing. I recommend using `toString(charset)` explicitly.

Comment: I see, simple. Kotlin makes things simpler seems like. Just need to learn more about the language. Thanks for your answer, I will try it.

Comment: ByteArray.stringFromUtf8 seems to be only available for native code?

Answer (score 29):

You can try this
**String(data, Charsets.UTF_8)**

Reference : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-string.html

Comment: Thanks man, this should be accepted answer, Simple, easy and well defined 
Thanks again

Answer (score 17):

using kotlin function as

```
charset("UTF-8")
```

using from  your data

```
 String(response.data, charset("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin 1.4 provides a common [`ByteArray.decodeToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/decode-to-string.html) function.

It takes a `ByteArray` containing bytes of string encoded with utf8 encoding and decodes it to kotlin `String`. So you can use it like:

```
val response: String = response.data.decodeToString()
```

Comment: Do you think this is the better way to go? Presumably, this would mean that ByteArray,decodeToString() will be the new way to doing things and ByteArray.toString() may be deprecated (or not supported), right?

Comment: I have the same thoughts. Been stuck on this today and I can't really find the real implementation under `ByteArray.toString()` to see what's the Charset used. I assume there has to be some.

Comment: @Vuco use `decodeToString` function, you can be certain that it uses UTF-8 charset.

Comment: I found the implementation under the `toString()` method. If called on a complex object, Java executes the `Object.toString()`, which, as stated in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), returns a string that "textually represents" this object, following the pattern `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. It is advised to override this method for each subclass of the `Object` class. Just in case someone wondered what's behind the curtain :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extension method to convert string to UTF_8 format.

```
fun String.toUTF8String(): String {
    val bytes = this.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    return bytes.decodeToString()
}
```

**Explanation**

First string is converted to ByteArray using UTF_8 character set. Then convert that ByteArray to string using [`ByteArray.decodeToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/decode-to-string.html) function provided in Kotlin 1.4.

[`ByteArray.decodeToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/decode-to-string.html) function takes a ByteArray containing bytes of string encoded with utf8 encoding and decodes it to kotlin String. So you can use it like:

```
val utf8String = "Stack Overflow!".toUTF8String()
```